# problem with filtering some parts of text file in bash

Tags: python, bash

I have a file like the small example:
small example:

```
>ENSG00000004142|ENST00000003607|POLDIP2|||2118
Sequence unavailable
>ENSG00000003056|ENST00000000412|M6PR|9099001;9102084|9099001;9102551|2756
CCAGGTTGTTTGCCTCTGGTCGGAAAGGGAAACTACCCCTGCTTCCACTCTGACAGCAGA
```

but I have too many "Sequence unavailable". I want to get rid of those transcripts. and the results would be like this:

```
>ENSG00000003056|ENST00000000412|M6PR|9099001;9102084|9099001;9102551|2756
CCAGGTTGTTTGCCTCTGGTCGGAAAGGGAAACTACCCCTGCTTCCACTCTGACAGCAGA
```

I tried to filter out those parts in bash using

```
grep -A 2 "Sequence" your.fa | grep -v "\-\-" | sed -n '/Sequence/!p' > new.fa
```

but it just removes "Sequence unavailable" but not its header (the line starts with `">"` above each sequence which is identifier for each sequence)

how can I filter out them in bash or python?

Comment: If you want to remove the whole row, use `grep -v "Sequence unavailable"`.

Comment: using the mentioned code I can remove the whole row. but I also want to remove the above row which is its identifier.

Comment: Will there always be one row above `Sequence unavailable` which needs to be removed?

Comment: yes. like example

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the row containing `Sequence unavailable` as well as the row above should be removed, one can use this sed:

```
$ sed '$!N;/\nSequence unavailable$/d;P;D' input
```

Basically it works by reading two lines into the pattern space at the time, then printing the top one, and removing it from the pattern space, so leaving the current line in the pattern space, which result in always being a row behind:

```
$!N;                               # Append Next line to pattern space unless
                                   # there are no more lines
    /\nSequence unavailable$/d     # Delete whole pattern space if regex is matched
                               P;  # Print first line of pattern space
                                 D # Delete first line of pattern space
```

The above works in GNU sed, one might need to change `;D` for `;$!D;q` to make to work with a strictly POSIX sed or one would have an endless loop.